# Deploy Flask and Tensorflow serving on Google App Engine

Tags: python, docker, google-app-engine, gunicorn, tensorflow-serving

I want to deploy Flask API with gunicorn and tensorflow serving to Google App Engine (Flex). I wrote a Dockerfile and startup.sh but fails to deploy. I increased memory to 6GB and set timeout 2 min for gunicorn, but it doesn't help.

Dockerfile runs successfully but startup.sh doesn't launch both of gunicorn and tensorflow serving. Can anybody point out what's wrong in sartup.sh?

Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.7
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

RUN apt-get update
ADD app/ /app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

RUN echo "deb http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable tensorflow-model-server tensorflow-model-server-universal" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tensorflow-serving.list && \
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y tensorflow-model-server

RUN apt-get install -y nginx
COPY app/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

WORKDIR /root

RUN chmod -R a+r /var/www/html

COPY startup.sh /startup.sh
RUN chmod 744 /startup.sh
RUN cd /
CMD /startup.sh
```

startup.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/nginx start
cd /app && nohup gunicorn app:app --bind 127.0.0.1:8081 --workers 1 --timeout 120 &
nohup tensorflow_model_server \
  --rest_api_port=8501 \
  --model_name=bird_net \
  --model_base_path=/app/saved_model &
```

Standard error output

```
$ gcloud app deploy
...
(ommited)
...
bc9f3e1065bb: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:8dd67b5292199744a51d58c3cafb5ff17b87c4b39e35589c0d44e646dc1dd272 size: 5567
DONE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                          
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED
 * Starting nginx nginx
   ...done.
```

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow you have to point out what's wrong or doesn't work and we try to help. So, what's the actual problem?

Comment: Exactly you're right. I added. I've no idea how to run two processes, gunicorn and tensroflow serving. I let them in background process by nohup ... &, but gunicorn doesn't seem to launch. When launched on forground, gunicorn starts well. Tensorflow serving is as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved. Docker needs at least one foreground process.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
/etc/init.d/nginx start
cd /app
gunicorn app:app --bind 127.0.0.1:8081 --workers 1 --timeout 120 &
tensorflow_model_server \
  --rest_api_port=8501 \
  --model_name=birdnet \
  --model_base_path=/app/saved_model
fg %1
```

References
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/